# Unable to import core Ballerina module

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to update a Ballerina module to Swan Lake beta 2. After switching my distribution to `slbeta2`, I try to build it with `bal build` and get an error on an import. The offending line of code is:

```
import ballerina/random as rnd;
```

The error is "cannot resolve module 'ballerina/random as rnd'".

Changing my code to

```
import ballerina/random;
```

doesn't help any, I still get the error "cannot resolve module 'ballerina/random'".

It looks like [this module still exists and has been updated for this distribution](https://docs.central.ballerina.io/ballerina/random/0.10.0-beta.2).

From what I can see in the reference examples, the syntax of imports hasn't changed in this distribution.

What am I doing wrong?

Update: I tried reinstalling Ballerina but there was no apparent effect.

Comment: I tried the following on slbeta2, but this seems to work for me.

`import ballerina/random; public function main() { float decimalResult = random:createDecimal(); } `

What was the version you were using previously? Can you also please share the output of `bal -v`?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce as well. Should be an issue with the version.

Comment: ```bal -v``` says:

Ballerina Swan Lake Beta 2
Language specification 2021R1
Update Tool 1.3.5

Comment: And I was previously at ```slalpha2```.

Comment: @pmext In VSCode, do you see `Ballerina SDK: Swan Lake Beta 2` at bottom left corner (in the blue strip)? And in ballerina vscode plugin settings, do you have the `Developer Mode` ticked?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA Ballerina plugin doesn't support `Ballerina Swan Lake` versions. It only supports Ballerina 1.x versions. You will have to use vscode with ballerina plugin installed for that.

Comment: I'm not using the IDE to run code at all, my question is just about trying to compile and run with the command line tool.

Comment: If you are on ubuntu, can you try again after removing `~/.ballerina` (`.ballerina` folder in your home directory). On windows `C:\Users\${username}\.ballerina` directory should be deleted.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. Unfortunately, deleting that directory did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing my project to [the current suggested structure](https://ballerina.io/learn/user-guide/ballerina-packages/package-layout/), I found that I had a file called `Ballerina.lock` which is no longer required. I don't recall how it got there but it appears to be a predecessor of `Dependencies.toml`. Removing that stopped the error.